# Error on using usercontrol on umbraco azure

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

The user control that I am using is working perfectly on my umbraco ie installed on local machine but when I uploaded it on the azure website the user control is showing errors like these

```
  Error reading usercontrols/MdriveReg.ascx

    The following list shows the Public Properties from the Control. By checking the Properties and click the "Save Properties" button at the bottom, umbraco will create the corresponding Macro Elements.




       System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'MdriveUmbraco.MdriveReg'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'MdriveUmbraco.MdriveReg'. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'MdriveUmbraco.MdriveReg'. at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal() at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at umbraco.developer.assemblyBrowser.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that my .dll file was not loading properly so I created a new project coded it to my requirements and then I build it and placed it in to my umbraco running in windows azure it worked.

THE PROBLEM WAS WITH MY .dll FILE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Azure pro, but it looks like it can't load the assembly that your user control is referencing (MdriveUmbraco.dll?).

Does this assembly exist in the bin folder of the web site? Perhaps it's in the GAC of your local machine and thus not problematic there?

Do assemblies need to be signed to run in Azure? Perhaps you need to sign it?